# load content form controller in popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-hmvc

I want to load the content after submitting the form in a popup. i have try modal and dialog box which are predefined with a div and then on ajax call the data is appended any suggestion are very much helpful

Comment: More specifically, what do you mean by "customize file" not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember to add `$CI =& get_instance();` in your library's constructor or at the top of your helper file so you can use all the CodeIgniter resources in your libraries and helpers? (see also [here in the docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html))

You can then call CodeIgniter resources like this:

```
$CI->load->helper('file_helper');
read_file($file);    

$CI->load->library('session');
$CI->session->sess_destroy();
```

Comment: i like to re frame the question when i used the facebook php sdk in application/libraries it was showing error that class not found but when i put the same files in system/libraries it working fine so wats the difference ......Thanks in advance